# Getting last numeric index in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that has both a varying number of elements and varying types of associations, like so:

```
$example =
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => 100
    [2] => Some String

    ...

    [17] => 2
    [18] => 0
    [type] => Some String
    [inst] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some String
        )
    [method] => Some String

)

$other = 
Array
(
    [0] => 45678
    [1] => 250
    [2] => Some String

    ...

    [8] => 7
    [9] => -2
    [inst] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some String
            [1] => Some String
        )

)
```

What I'm trying to do is get the last numerical index in these arrays and some before it. Like, in the first example, I want to get `$example[18]` and in the second I want to return `$other[9]`.

I was using `count($array)-1` before the named associations came into play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[max](https://www.php.net/max)** and **[array_keys](https://www.php.net/array_keys)**

```
echo max(array_keys($array));
```

In case of a possibility of alphanumeric keys, you can use

<strike>echo intval(max(array_keys($array)));</strike>

```
echo max(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_int'));  
// hint taken from Amal's answer, but index calculation logic is still same as it was.
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/SZicJYJ5)**

Comment: Max evaluates strings as 0. Interesting, didn't know that. That's helpful. I figured an option was to use array_keys. +1

Comment: Yep, ***max***: `When given a string it will be cast as an integer when comparing. `

Comment: What if the array contains `("19xyz" => "value")`?

Comment: The number at the beginning is taken into consideration; xyz is ignored. "19xyz" would evaluate as "19." If you have numbers at the beginning of a string and don't want it to return those, then just using max won't work for you.

Comment: You can use intval() in any such case, but this answer was tailored to their structure. Let me see if we can add a clause while keeping it simple.

Comment: Yeah, but in theory that would only return "19" out of "19xyz." If you need to only get specifically a key that is a straight out integer with no text in it at all, a special method would need to be created.

Comment: My array keys are guaranteed to be non-numeric strings, so `max` works fine. Good to take that into consideration, though.

Comment: This would fail if the array keys aren't ordered. @Corey: you should make it clear whether you need exactly the *last* numeric key's value or the *greatest* numeric key's value.

Comment: It wont fail Amal. `max` doesn't care about order, but you're right about the confusion. @jrConway see the update.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Glad to know. But it's always better to avoid confusion. Since the OP accepted this answer, I assume that's what he wanted :)

Comment: I saw the update, looks pretty good. Its not necessarily needed in this case but its helpful to have around in case someone does need to know. Agreed on the confusion; I just caught that. If Corey is looking for the last value and not the max value this won't work the same way.

Comment: My elements are added with `array_push` in the same order every time, and elements are never overwritten. So unless there is some undocumented behavior I'm not aware of, both the max and end values should always be the same.

Answer (score 5):

If your array isn't ordered and you want to get the **last** numeric index, then you could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) as follows:

```
$numerickeys = array_filter(array_keys($example), 'is_int');
echo end($numerickeys); // => 18
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/69076)

Answer (score 1):

This one will always work as expected:

```
var_dump(max(array_filter(array_keys($example), 'is_int'))); # int(18)
var_dump(max(array_filter(array_keys($other), 'is_int'))); # int(9)
```